# What is the correct coordinate system for google geocoded text file layers?

Tags: qgis, geocoding, web-mercator

When importing a text file containing lat/longs geocoded from something like GPSVisualizer.com into QGIS, what is the correct coordinate system to select?

Most web services (GpsVisualizer included) geocode in Web Mercator, but QGIS has no Web Mercator coordinate option.

Comment: For extra points, which coordinate system should be selected in ArcGIS? Are google and yahoo maps the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your coordinates are in lat/long degrees, the correct CRS is `EPSG:4326`.

Web Mercator is `EPSG:3857` (identically to EPSG:900913), but that has "metres" as units. These metres are only at the equator identically to real metres.